How to prevent reboot on a CD4017?
First, I must say that I am a novice in circuit design. Let me explain what I want to do: I want to turn on the LEDs sequentially by pressing the button, from output 0 to output 8. and when I get to the 9th output (even if I press the button) I don't want the queue to go back to the beginning. When I just press the button connected to the reset, the sequence should return to the beginning. The circuit in the picture worked for a while, but then it stopped working. However, when I disconnect the 11th and 14th pins, the circuit works, but the circuit returns to the beginning after the 9th output. So I have two questions: Is there something wrong with the schematic and how do I make the circuit stop when I get to output 9? Finally, I'm sorry, my English is not very good.


Please redraw the circuit with at least the switches shown as schematic symbols instead of their ambiguous physical connections. Labeling the IC's pins with the pin name instead of the number would help as well.

Disable the clock by connecting pin11(Q9) to pin13(clock inhibit).

this didn't work. I connected pin 13 to pin 11. I disconnected all connections to Pin 14.

Pin14 is clock input, it has to be connected to button.

After connecting pin 11 and pin 13, where should I connect pin 14?

In your drawing you connect pin numbers 1 (5), 2 (1), 4 (2), 5 (6), 6 (7), 7 (3) all together! It would not work like you described! That are push and pull outputs, from datasheet from TI, that shouldn't be connected to each other! Your drawing does not represent reality. Perhaps your schematic should look more like this from this german page?

So, can you please explain roughly what kind of connection I need to make to turn on the same LED with 8 outputs? I cannot understand the circuit in the link you sent, I am a student.

@YusufY. - Hi, It seems like this question is obsolete and it has been superseded by your later question here. Therefore I have closed this one as a duplicate of that later one. In future, please be careful to avoid having multiple open overlapping questions. Otherwise people could waste time on this one, when they should be focusing on the later question instead. TY

Thanks for the warning, I had forgotten about this. I will pay attention.
